# Get next page url scrapy

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

From a list of urls like this one:

```
<a href="?resultpage=3&amp;p_department=RL&amp;propertyAddress=&amp;propertyType=&amp;minimumBedrooms=&amp;maximumBedrooms=&amp;minimumPrice=&amp;minimumRentFrequency=pcm&amp;maximumPrice=&amp;maximumRentFrequency=pcm">3</a>

<a href="?resultpage=2&amp;p_department=RL&amp;propertyAddress=&amp;propertyType=&amp;minimumBedrooms=&amp;maximumBedrooms=&amp;minimumPrice=&amp;minimumRentFrequency=pcm&amp;maximumPrice=&amp;maximumRentFrequency=pcm" title="Next">Next &gt;</a>
```

How can I only get the one that has the attribute: title="Next">Next?

Using:

```
//@href
```

The value " title="Next">Next" is lose, so it can't be used the filter the urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response.xpath("//a[@title='Next']/@href").extract_first()
```